# Getting a type error when try to display data from API using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

What I am trying to accomplish is displaying the data (name and email) from the API call that I made and then filter() the results from typing in the input field the name that I want to see.

When I am just simply trying to display the list of names or in this case just one it gives me a type error message

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Below is the code that I have in this simple app for learning/testing purposes.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(res => {
      setSelected(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(selected);
  // console.log(selected.name)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Names below</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setSearch(e.target.value);

          const name = selected.filter(
            select => select.name === search,
            selected
          );
        }}
      />
      <div className="list">{selected[0].name}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here since you are making a axios call in an useEffect call, the value of selected is `null` before the useEffect call happens.
Thus since the selected.filter runs on null (as filter is a method of an array) it returns an error
So you need to set `selected` to default to `[]` i.e.
`const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);` or you need to return `null` before the final return if the value of selected is null so it doesn't render anything until the value of selected is populated

```
if(!selected) {
  return null;
}
```

I have added a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/acesmndr/qrjL4cnt/8/)

Comment: Ok so I made that change and have the default state as an open array but I'm not sure why I am not able to read the data in the array for Selected though?

This is coming from just simply trying to call selected[0].name to display

Comment: It's because it's directly trying to access the first item from an empty array. so you need to check if the array has a length before displaying it or the easier way is to check for null before the axios request has been made. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/acesmndr/qrjL4cnt/8/

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://codesandbox.io/s/long-platform-u81q3 regularly!

You can render the name part when selected object does exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give this a shot as it filters as you type in names

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(res => {
      setSelected(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(selected);
  // console.log(selected.name)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Names below</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setSearch(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {selected &&
        selected
          .filter(
            select => select.name.toLowerCase().includes(search),
            selected
          )
          .map(select => <div className="list">{select.name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This works and I made a change to start the select state to start as an empty array instead.

Comment: Awesome that's better !!